# inner-join mysql x3

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to display cust_id, the customer forename and surname, the product name<-(from products table) and date of sale<--(from sales table), also I need to display in order of the most recent dates first.

This is what I have got so far:

```
SELECT   
   customer.cust_id, 
   customer.forename, 
   customer.surname, 
   products.prod_name, 
   sales.Date_of_sale
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN sales s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
    INNER JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
ORDER BY s.Date_of_sale DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be consistent when you use aliases, use them instead of table names in the select part too. Apart from that the query looks correct (not knowing the schema though).

Comment: you are creating the alias for table names so you may need the same in select statement i.e. `c.customer_id`..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
SELECT   
   c.cust_id, 
   c.forename, 
   c.surname, 
   p.prod_name, 
   s.Date_of_sale
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN sales s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
    INNER JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
ORDER BY s.Date_of_sale DESC
```

will work